# shared scope between a content script and an injected script in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My content scrip injects a script from a remote server:

```
function addScript(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = callback;
    script.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

addScript("https://www.example.com/remoteScript.js", function (){...});
```

But the injected script does not seem to be able to access variables which where added to the DOM of the window by the content script:

content script:

```
window.methods = {
    method1: function () {...}
};
```

injected script:

```
window.methods.method1();    // <---- does NOT work. window.methods undefined.
```

This might be due to security reasons related to DOM manipulation.

Is there a way to achieve something similar? Some kind of a shared global context?

Comment: Contents scripts can access the DOM. What do you mean? And what exactly is a remote script?

Comment: Yes, this was not clear, I have elaborated in the question.

Comment: Content scripts run in isolated world so no, there's no shared context. Use messaging.